# C: Copying a smaller section of memory onto a larger one without knowing the smaller ones size, as in realloc()

Tags: memory, memory-management, memcpy, realloc

How does the realloc function (c), which only takes the length of the *new* section of memory, copy the *old* (smaller, to force the situation in question) section of memory to the *new* one? (this is assuming it needs to, as in, the memory could not be found contiguous to the *old* block to extend it)

If it coppied the full size (the second arg to realloc) from the smaller section, it would be reading from invalid memory, right?

Thanks,
J

EDIT: code illustrating an extreme example:

```
int main ( void ) {
  unsigned int i=0;
  void *test_ptr1, *test_ptr2;

  // this first bit just finds the size of the available heap, ignore it if you wish
  do {
    free(test_ptr1); 
    printf("%u\n",i);
    i+=1073741824; // 1GiB
  } while ((test_ptr1 = malloc(i)));
  i-=1073741824;
  do {
    free(test_ptr1); 
    printf("%u\n",i);
    i+=1048576; // 1MiB
  } while ((test_ptr1 = malloc(i)));
  i-=1048576;
  do {
    free(test_ptr1); 
     printf("%u\n",i);
     i+=1024; // 1KiB
  } while ((test_ptr1 = malloc(i)));
  i-=1024;
  do {
    free(test_ptr1);
    printf("%u\n",i); 
    i+=128; // 128B
  } while ((test_ptr1 = malloc(i)));
  i-=128;
  do {
    free(test_ptr1);
    printf("%u\n",i); 
    i++; // 1B
  } while ((test_ptr1 = malloc(i)));
  i--;

  // i is now equal to the size of the available heap (I think...)

  test_ptr1 = calloc(i-1, 1); // calloc all but one byte of the available heap
  test_ptr2 = malloc(1); // malloc the reamining byte
  printf("proving calloc: %u\n", ((char *)test_ptr1)[i-2]); // outputs 0, this might be a point of weakness int this program, if this is optimised in any way it fails to demonstrate the effect
  *(char *)test_ptr2 = 'c'; // initialise the byte to 'c'
  free(test_ptr1); // free the vast majority of the heap
  if ((test_ptr1 = realloc(test_ptr2, i-1))) { // realloc the one byte to the space taken up by the previous calloc that was freed in the previous line
    printf("realloc success: %c\n", *(char *)test_ptr1); // outputs c, but whats in the rest of this memory section? and more informatively, where was it coppied from?
    getc(stdin);
    free(test_ptr1);
    free(test_ptr2);
    return 0; 
  } else {
    printf("realloc failed\n");
    free(test_ptr2);
    return -1;
  }
}
```

output:

```
1945305043
1945305044
1945305045
1945305046
1945305047
1945305048
1945305049
1945305050
1945305051
1945305052
1945305053
1945305054
1945305055
1945305056
proving calloc: 0
realloc success: c
```

Comment: If there is anyone else wanting to know an answer to this question you might be interested in this link: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/600170-implementing-realloc it was very useful, but read the whole thing b/c there is some bad info in the first few posts.

Answer (score 1):

> If it coppied the full size (the second arg to realloc) from the
>   smaller section, it would be reading from invalid memory, right?

Right you are, take a look at the documentation:

> The content of the memory block is preserved up to the lesser of the
>   new and old sizes, even if the block is moved to a new location. **If
>   the new size is larger, the value of the newly allocated portion is
>   indeterminate.**

Comment: ok, thanks, but how does it know how much of the new section is indeterminate? (so that it doesnt copy this part from the old section and run into invalid memory) this value would be new_size-old_size but it doesnt know the value of old_size (or does it?)

Comment: It does not know! It takes a pointer to the begin of the memory block and simply "cut" the given size!

Comment: So if I understand you correctly the "indeterminate" memory in the new section will be of the same value as the invalid memory contiguous to the old section? Is this not a security hole? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, but the primary aim of the realloc is to change the size of the memory block. The documantation says: The function may move the memory block to a new location ...

Comment: What would happen if I: allocated all but a little bit of the heap (at the end), then allocated that little bit, freed the very large section and realloced the smaller seation to fill the larger section; would this fail, be filled with data from another process, or ??

Comment: I have added some code above. I think it proves that the process is more complicated than just a block copy or, that during the copy, when the process reaches the end of the available memory it starts copying from the begining again.

Comment: It seems not working properly: output is "Timeout" http://codepad.org/prTlASzP (probably the while loop)

Comment: unsuprised it timed out on an online compile/execute, its not exactly the worlds best/most efficient code... have added the last bits of the output from my machine above. ty